# Putnam 2001 - Problem A-1 (On a binary operation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, recreational-mathematics, contest-math, binary-operations

Let $*$ be a binary operation acting on a set $S$, such that $$(a*b)*a=b,$$ for all $a,b\in S$.

Prove that $$a*(b*a)=b,$$ for all $a,b \in S$.

Comment: The solution in mathlinks says $((b*a)*b)(b*a)=b$ out of the blue. Why?

Comment: Let $a=(b*a),b=b.$

Comment: what do you mean let $a=b*a$

Comment: @coffeemath can we just go ahead and say $a=(b*a)$ is that legit?

Comment: user4140 Yes it's legit. To se it rewrite (a*b)*a=b with new letters like (x*y)*x=y, then let this x be (a*b) and this y be b.

Comment: Can we say that a*a =1 ( as in the identity element?) also can we also say a*b=b*a ?? or does the hypothesis need to say commutative?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have that
$$
a*(b*a)=\big((b*a)*b\big)*(b*a)=b
$$
Note that the second "=" holds since
$$
(c*b)*c=b,
$$
where $c=b*a$.

Comment: yes, the only part I don't get is the second equivalence

Comment: Why is $((b*a)*b)*(b*a)=b$???

Comment: I really don't understand it. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @user4140: See update.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I finally get it. Thanks.

Comment: The fact you used a different variable made it clear to me. a=a*b really confused me

Answer (score 2):

Because $b*a,b\in S$, so by the formula $((b*a)*b)*(b*a)=b$. Then $a*(b*a)=b$.

Comment: By what formula?

Comment: @user4140 By the formula $a∗(b∗a)=b$, just replace $a$ by $a*b$.